# mutual reference in function definition

Tags: parsing, haskell

`some` & `many` defined [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v:some) have internal expressions which refer to each other. I'm finding this difficult to understand.

```
some :: f a -> f [a]
some v = some_v
  where
    many_v = some_v <|> pure []
    some_v = (:) <$> v <*> many_v

-- | Zero or more.
many :: f a -> f [a]
many v = many_v
  where
    many_v = some_v <|> pure []
    some_v = (:) <$> v <*> many_v
```

What would be the type signatures of `many_v` and `some_v`?

How does the following get evaluated (using `parsec`)?

```
Prelude Text.Parsec> parse (many (oneOf "abc")) mempty "abc"
Right "abc"
```

Comment: It can be read as "many means either some or none at all" and "some means one item followed by many". This recursive definition makes "many" mean "0 or more" and "some" mean "1 or more". Very close to a context-free-grammar definition.

Comment: The execution of the `v` parameter—an Alternative action—is expected to "fail" eventually, putting an end to the recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

both of the functions have signatures like

```
many_v :: (Alternative f) => f [a]
some_v :: (Alternative f) => f [a]
```

Replacing bindings with their definitions you can simplify

```
some v = some_v
  where
    some_v = (:) <$> v <*> (some_v <|> pure [])

many v = many_v
  where
    many_v = ( (:) <$> v <*> many_v) <|> pure []
```

---

```
some v = (:) <$> v <*> (some v <|> pure [])
many v = ((:) <$> v <*> many v) <|> pure []
```

---

Normally you define these functions simply as

```
many v = some v <|> pure []
some v = (:) <$> v <*> many v
```

In most projects recursive functions are defined worker wrapper functions in order to enable compiler do more optimizations

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at `some_v = (:) <$> v <*> many_v`. We know

```
v :: f a
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
(<$>) :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

Then:

```
(:) <$> v :: f ([a] -> [a])
```

Let's now look at `<*> :: Applicative f => f (x -> y) -> f x -> f y`. First arg is `(:) <$> v :: f ([a] -> [a])`, so `x ~ [a]` and `y ~ [a]`. And that means, that `many_v :: f [a]` and `some_v :: f [a]`.

Also let's check `many_v = some_v <|> pure []` definition. We have:

```
pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a
(<|>) :: Alternative f => f a -> f a -> f a
```

So:

```
pure [] :: f [a]
some_v :: f [a]
-- so we have:
some_v <|> pure [] :: f [a]
-- and by definition
many_v :: f [a]
```